# How to remove the space taken by date not appear in the data in a date plot?

Tags: r

For the following input,

```
Date    Visits
11/1/2010   696537
11/3/2010   799355
11/4/2010   805800
11/5/2010   701262
11/6/2010   531579
11/7/2010   690068
11/8/2010   756947
11/10/2010  701768
11/11/2010  820113
11/12/2010  645259
```

When I run the following code, I see 11/3/2010 still takes a space. Is there a way to remove the space taken by that date in the plot? What is the general method to skip all the dates not in the data?

```
f$Date <- as.Date(f$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
plot(Visits ~ Date, f, xaxt = "n", type = "l")
axis(1, f$Date, format(f$Date, "%b %d"), cex.axis = .7)
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an x axis that is not commensurate with the actual time elapsed? (I'm guessing that you meant to write that 11/2/2010 was still creating a gap between 11/3/ and 11/1.) If that is the case, then use seq_along(Date) as your X-axis. I think it should work in the  formula, but if not then use the plot(x=..., y=..) style of plotting call.

Comment: No. I want to delete the gap space at the 11/2/2010 in addition to not show the tick at 11/2/2010.

Comment: Your code includes all `f$Date` in the `axis(.)`. Why do you think R should explicitly ignore the `at=` and `labels=` arguments?

Comment: I don't know. You can show me the code that does not let the date not appeared in the data to take the spaces.

Comment: Your `x` axis is continuous, so it will keep the gaps appropriately. If you want it to be categorical, you need to change your data from `Date` class to strings. However, this to me seems odd: gaps in the timeline are relevant, even if they have no data in them.

Comment: In my case, it is not relevant. So I want to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't seem to pick up on my comment, I'm including it here after testing. The underlying x-axis scale is now integers starting from 1.

```
 f <- read.table(text="Date    Visits
 11/1/2010   696537
 11/3/2010   799355
 11/4/2010   805800
 11/5/2010   701262
 11/6/2010   531579
 11/7/2010   690068
 11/8/2010   756947
 11/10/2010  701768
 11/11/2010  820113
 11/12/2010  645259", head=T)
 f$Date <- as.Date(f$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
 plot(Visits ~ seq_along(Date), f, xaxt = "n", type = "l")
 axis(1, seq_along(f$Date), format(f$Date, "%b %d"), cex.axis = .7)
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, do you know which `plot()` function is called? I want to see why a formula can be accepted by a plot function. I see these `plot.default         plot.new             plot.ts
plot.design          plot.spec.coherency  plot.window
plot.ecdf            plot.spec.phase      plot.xy
plot.function        plot.stepfun`. But I don't know which one is used for ploting the formula `Visits ~ seq_along(Date)`.

Comment: The function called is `plot.formula`. If you want to see the code you might need to type `getAnywhere(plot.formula)` at the console since some `plot` methods are not exported. You can see all the S3 plot methods that are currently in your workspace with `methods(plot)` . Function names with trailing asterisk are "hidden".

Comment: When plot.formula should be used? When plot.default should be used? For this case, can plot(x, y, ...) styple be used as well?

Comment: Not sure what is meant by the first and second  questions. Re #3: I don't see why not. In fact, my comment explicitly said that's what I would have tried if `plot.formula` failed to execute `seq_along` properly when it was in the RHS of the formula. I'm wondering if you should look at `help(pac=graphics)` and `?device`